Can we characterize the stable sets of a self-map?
If $E$ is a set and $f : E \to E$ is any map from $E$ to itself, a subset $S \subseteq E$ is said to be stable if $\forall s \in S, f(s) \in S$, i.e. if $f[S] \subseteq S$.
Clearly, the set $\mathbf{St}(f)$ of stable subsets satisfy the following properties:

$E$ and $\varnothing$ are in $\mathbf{St}(f)$;
$\mathbf{St}(f)$ is closed under (arbitrary) intersections and unions. (If you prever, you might want to see the first property as a particular case of this one, when the index set is empty).

I cannot find other properties satisfied by $\mathbf{St}(f)$ in general. My question is:

Is there a list of such properties that characterize the set of subsets $\mathscr S \subset \mathscr P(\mathscr P(E))$ which can be written as $\mathbf{St}(f)$ for some self-map $f$?


I'm slightly less interested in sets satisfying $f[S] = S$ but if you have any information about those, feel free to share!

A small reformulation/equivalence maybe ? $s \in S$ implies $f(s) \in S$ which you can apply recursively to deduce that the whole orbit ${f^n(s) : n \in \mathbb{N}}$ must be in $S$. The converse is also obviously true. Thus $S$ is stable iff it is also closed under the map $S \to \mathrm{Orbit_f}(S)$.

As I said in my comment to Martin Brandenburg's answer, I missed two general conditions:  1. every element of  is an element of a countable stable set and 2. every stable set is the union of a family of countable stable sets. (Here, countable means finite or countable.)

A family $\mathcal{T}$ of subsets of $E$ is stable under all intersections and unions if and only if it is an Alexandrov topology on $E$, and it is well-known that these correspond to preorders on $E$. Explicitly, $x \leq y$ holds iff every set in $\mathcal{T}$ containing $y$ also contains $x$. Conversely, the sets in $\mathcal{T}$ are the lower sets of the preorder.
The preorder induced by a map $f : E \to E$ is then defined as follows: We have $x \leq y$ iff every $f$-stable set containing $y$ also contains $x$. Since $\{f^n(y) : n \geq 0\}$ is the smallest $f$-stable subset containing $y$, we see that
$$x \leq y \iff \exists n \geq 0 \, : x = f^n(y).$$
Your question is equivalent to a characterization of those preorders on $E$ that are induced by a map $f : E \to E$ in this way.
Certainly, not every preorder has this form. Notice that every interval $E_{\leq y} := \{x \in E : x \leq y \}$ must be countable. It seems to be a quite strong assumption.

Thank you very much for your answer. "Alexandrov topology" is definitely a keyword I needed. Your answer also made me realise I missed two pretty simple general conditions: 1. every element of $E$ is an element of a countable stable set and 2. every stable set is the union of a family of countable stable sets. Maybe this is enough?

I don't think so. And notice that 2) is equivalent to 1).

@PseudoNeo That is not enough. Consider, for example, the collection of all upwards closed subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$. It satisfies all the conditions currently written down, but is not the collection of stable sets of any $f$.

You're right: the upsets $x^\uparrow$ have a very specific (pre)order isomorphism type. They are either order-isomorphic to a finite set $P(r,n) = {x < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_r \sim x_{r+1} \sim \cdots \sim x_n}$ or order-isomorphic to $(\mathbb N, \leq)$.

A consequence of this property of the upsets is that, if $x$ is not alone in its equivalence class, then it is a maximal element (in the proset sense: if $x \leq y$, then $x \sim y$).

I think you mean the down sets. Sorry I fixed the order order after posting because it wasn't the official one.
